# 3D Pucker as user's location mapbox ios

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapbox, mapbox-ios

I am using [Mapbox Maps iOS](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-maps-ios) to [create a custom 3d pucker](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-maps-ios/blob/main/Apps/Examples/Examples/All%20Examples/Custom3DPuckExample.swift) and use that to display the user's location.

Everything seems to be working, the camera redirects to the user's location, the pucker successfully loads. However, I am having trouble setting the pucker's location to the user's location.

You can see that I am required to set the `location` of the pucker in the `Model` instance in the `loadCharacter()` function. But I am unsure of how to link that to the user's current location.

Please help!!!

```
// ViewController.swift

import UIKit
import MapboxMaps


public class ViewController: UIViewController {
    internal var mapView: MapView!
    internal var cameraLocationConsumer: CameraLocationConsumer!

    override public func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let options = MapInitOptions(cameraOptions: CameraOptions(zoom: 16))

        mapView = MapView(frame: view.bounds, mapInitOptions: options)
        mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        view.addSubview(mapView)
        
        
        mapView.mapboxMap.onNext(.styleLoaded) { _ in
            self.loadCharacter()
        }
        
        cameraLocationConsumer = CameraLocationConsumer(mapView: mapView)
        
        mapView.mapboxMap.onNext(.mapLoaded) { _ in
            self.mapView.location.addLocationConsumer(newConsumer: self.cameraLocationConsumer)
        }
    }
    
    
    internal func loadCharacter() {

        let uri = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "race_car_model",
                                  withExtension: "gltf")

        // Instantiate the model
        let myModel = Model(uri: uri,
                            position: [-77.150925, 39.085006],
                            orientation: [0, 0, 180])

        // Setting an expression to  scale the model based on camera zoom
        let scalingExpression = Exp(.interpolate) {
            Exp(.linear)
            Exp(.zoom)
            0
            Exp(.literal) {
                [256000.0, 256000.0, 256000.0]
            }
            4
            Exp(.literal) {
                [40000.0, 40000.0, 40000.0]
            }
            8
            Exp(.literal) {
                [2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0]
            }
            12
            Exp(.literal) {
                [100.0, 100.0, 100.0]
            }
            16
            Exp(.literal) {
                [7.0, 7.0, 7.0]
            }
            20
            Exp(.literal) {
                [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
            }
        }

        let configuration = Puck3DConfiguration(model: myModel, modelScale: .expression(scalingExpression))
        mapView.location.options.puckType = .puck3D(configuration)

    }
}


// Create class which conforms to LocationConsumer, update the camera's centerCoordinate when a locationUpdate is received
public class CameraLocationConsumer: LocationConsumer {
    weak var mapView: MapView?

    init(mapView: MapView) {
        self.mapView = mapView
    }
    

    public func locationUpdate(newLocation: Location) {

        mapView?.camera.ease(
            to: CameraOptions(center: newLocation.coordinate, zoom: 16, pitch: 50.0),
            duration: 1.3)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mapbox has a repo with examples of navigation use cases that you can try, including [3D puck sample](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-ios-examples/blob/main/Navigation-Examples/Examples/Custom-User-Location.swift).

Note that this sample uses API from Navigation SDK, which in turn uses Maps SDK API internally. Fortunately, Navigation SDK is open-sourced, you can always look at how it draws current user location [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-ios/blob/main/Sources/MapboxNavigation/NavigationMapView.swift).